# Huge fonts in Google Chrome after update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

After update to 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit) I've got weird, totally huge fonts in the Chrome UI, including tabs titles, bookmarks bar and context menu. It makes the browser hardly usable - e.g. when I have > 8 open tabs I just can't read their titles, and also it looks really ugly[image: ugly huge fonts]

How can I make fonts normal again?